# can i call right and left function in this Object

Tags: javascript

```
const person = {
  name: "JONY SINS",
  age: 25,
  walk() {
    let anotherPerson = {
      right() {
        console.log("right");
      },
      left() {
        console.log("left");
      },
    };
    console.log(this);
  },
};
```

is it possible to call right() and left() function in this object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: No, you can't. They're properties of a `anotherPerson` variable inside the `person.walk()` function, but there's no way to access local variables outside the function.

Comment: You could do it if `walk()` ended with `return anotherPerson;`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`anotherPerson` is a local variable inside the `walk()` method. This variable can only be accessed inside the method. You could call `anotherPerson.left()` from inside `walk()`, but you can't call it from outside the method.

If the method returned the variable, you could call `walk()` and then call `left()` or `right()` from the returned value.

```js
const person = {
  name: "JONY SINS",
  age: 25,
  walk() {
    let anotherPerson = {
      right() {
        console.log("right");
      },
      left() {
        console.log("left");
      },
    };
    console.log("walk");
    return anotherPerson;
  },
};

let other = person.walk();
other.left();
other.right();
```